# How to preserve domain name without breaking the links with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a webpage ***www.mydomain.com*** but when someone access ***www.mydomain.com/DOMAIN2*** it should keep the main domain name and just open ***www.domain2.com*** inside it so it looks like it is in the same domain. I managed to create the redirect preserving the domain but when I click on any link inside domain2 I receive a NOT FOUND error message.

```
   #My Config
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^.*MYDOMAIN2/?$ http://www.mydomain2.com/$1 [P]
```

I did a lot of research on the internet but couldn't find the answer. Maybe used the wrong key words. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: so you want to say that you can create a website where yoursite.com/google will load and operate like google? no

Comment: That's a good analogy, but in my case the domain2 is a small website with some subdirectories and some static links.